# Should I use a Java ORM or should I use my own sql queries? Or maybe a mix of both?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, spring-jdbc

Here's currently what my database looks like and I have it hooked up properly with the Java Spring boot application. I would like to use some of the benefits of having a ORM but also would like to know if I can also write my own sql queries if need be.

Though I'm new to using ORM's and could use some advice on if it's possible to use a mix of an ORM and a raw sql queries.

[ER-Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssJTC.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface that extends JpaRepository or CrudRepository.

```
public interface <YourClassRepository> extends JpaRepository<YourClass, YourClassId> {

@Query("Your Query")
method();

}
```

This will allow you to perform CRUD operations.

If you want to use SQL for other purpose then you can use @Query

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Answer (score 0):

This Question is opinion based.

However if you use an ORM Layer you can save time and code for the basic create read update and delete operations (see example from @iamsan).
The ORM layer makes sense in a lot of cases but there is no simple answer for your question. It depends on what you are doing and what you want to achieve.
If you want to implement ORM for learing, do it.

I am using it for a while now and it makes the persistense a lot easier. However you might have to deal with some configuration first.

These are just my two cents, you might get different answers from other users.